# Excel VBA - compare data from row to line and highlight match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating an easy planning tool on Excel to check the tasks of the projects that I have at hand.

What I aim to do is something that automatically fills a cell, when that cell is the interception of a value in a row and a line. For example, If I schedule something from Week 22 to Week 23, it fills the cell below the column labeled W23, in the line that I changed.
A picture to ilustrate:

[image: Pic]

How can I find, in a line, the match of a cell in a row vs. a column heading, and then format the corresponding match?

Comment: What is your question? Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.How can I find, in a line, the match of a cell in a row, and then format the corresponding match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting will do it for you.

1. Select the range of cells you wish to apply it to (in your case `C3:S6`
2. Create a new condition with the following formula:

   `=$A2=C$1`
3. Create another condition with the following formula:

   `=$B2=C$1`

(Be careful of the placement of the `$`)

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Haven't thought about conditional formatting for this... Thanks a lot